# Javascript library for faster loop calculation

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

I've been wondering, if there is a library for javascript, which can speed up loops.

Eg. I have in this script only used one loop, which takes a long time for large input values​​.

[JSFiddle 1](http://jsfiddle.net/KE9X2/1/)

```
for (d = Math.pow(10,-5), delta = -10; delta <= 0; d=d+Math.pow(10,-5)) {

        var current=WylyEatons(k, d, f);
        var delta = current - wanted;

}
```

In this script, I used two loops. The first performs a rough calculation, and the next a finer calculation.

[JSfiddle 2](http://jsfiddle.net/t3nkT/6/)

```
function calculate() {
    var wanted = document.getElementById('test').value;
    var k=1000000;
    var f=0.33;
    for (d = 1, delta = -10; delta <= 0; d=d+1) {

            var current=WylyEatons(k, d, f);
            var delta = current - wanted;

    }
    for (d = d-1*2, delta = -10; delta <= 0; d=d+Math.pow(10,-5)) {

            var current=WylyEatons(k, d, f);
            var delta = current - wanted;

    }
    document.getElementById('d').innerHTML = (d);
}
```

If there is no libraries, is there any standard methods that are typically used

Comment: Why would you need a loop? You can solve the equation in closed form.
Even if you can't there is a bunch a of faster methods for solving nonlinear equations than just calculating difference on every grid point. Simple Newton's method will do the trick. http://jsfiddle.net/tarabyte/KE9X2/2/

Comment: You are right, but yes it's because i have to solve some non-linear equations. But isn't it better to use the Secant Method?

Comment: Well Secant Method is just a linear approximation to Newton's one. If you can find derivatives analytically you don't need to use approximations.

Answer (score 0):

Using the WebCl API's opencl bindings for javascript, can get you serious performance, for embarrassingly parallel loops.(harnessing both cpu and gpu)

```
 https://www.khronos.org/webcl/
```